# exported data date and time points to current date and time

Tags: c#

i have a problem with this script. Whenever i export this set of codes to text file, i want it to be printed according to the date and time i chose, but it shows "Sales-23-07-2012" instead.

For example, i want the text file to be as "Sales - (the date i chose)" rather then "Sales-23-07-2012"  Kindly help.

```
   namespace MedicalDataExporter

{

    public partial class frmSales : Form
    {
        public frmSales()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    private void dtpFrom_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btnExtract_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SqlConnection objConn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=AKC-105DR-CMS01\\GLOCO;Initial Catalog=Medprac;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password="");

        objConn.Open();

        SqlCommand objCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT CONVERT(char(80), InvDate,3) AS InvDate,InvoiceNo,EmployerCode,TaxAmount + SubTotal AS Amount,'' AS Payment FROM Invoice WHERE (InvDate >= CONVERT(datetime, '"+dtpFrom.Text +"', 105 )) AND (InvDate <= CONVERT(datetime, '"+dtpTo.Text+"', 105))", objConn);

        SqlDataReader objReader;
        objReader = objCmd.ExecuteReader();

        System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream("C:\\CMSExportedData\\Sales-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") + ".txt", System.IO.FileMode.Create);
        System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(fs, System.Text.Encoding.Default);

        int count = 0;
        while (objReader.Read())
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                if (!objReader.IsDBNull(i))
                {
                    string s;
                    s = objReader.GetDataTypeName(i);
                    //MessageBox.Show(s);
                    if (objReader.GetDataTypeName(i) == "char")
                    {
                        sw.Write(objReader.GetString(i));
                    }
                    else if (objReader.GetDataTypeName(i) == "money")

                    {
                        sw.Write(objReader.GetSqlMoney(i).ToString());
                    }
                    else if (objReader.GetDataTypeName(i) == "nvarchar")
                    {
                        sw.Write(objReader.GetString(i));
                    }
                }
                if (i < 4)
                {
                    sw.Write("\t");
                }

            }
            count = count + 1;
            sw.WriteLine();

        }
        sw.Flush();
        fs.Close();
        objReader.Close();
        objConn.Close();
        MessageBox.Show(count + " records exported successfully.");
        this.Close();
    }

    private void groupBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void dtpTo_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void frmSales_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Well, where are you "choosing" your date value?  As it stands, you're _explicitly_ telling the filename to include `DateTime.Now`: `System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream("C:\\CMSExportedData\\Sales-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") + ".txt", System.IO.FileMode.Create);`

Comment: oh, i get what you mean, is there a way to print with the selected date and time, kind sir?

Comment: I'm not sure you do get what I mean... Where is there a selected date and time?  How is that value being "selected"?

Comment: hmm, guess my coding is pretty bad haha

Comment: Please look into the `using` statement and how you should manage the objects which implement `IDisposable` (which are quite numerous in your code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you really just post a full connection string with the admin password?

Anyway, replace `DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")`

with

```
myDateControlOnTheForm.Text
```

Comment: When i changed that it shows me this error 'The name 'myDateControlOnTheForm' does not exist in the current context'

Comment: @Newbie: That brings us back to the original question, which is where you're getting this value in the first place.  The answerer here was assuming you had some control on the form which was being used to input a date.  If you don't see that in the answer, then it sounds like the question is a bit misdirected.  You're not so much asking "How do I use a specific date?" but instead should be asking "How do I collect input from the user?" which is a very different question, and one that can probably best be answered by learning some basic C# application development from a tutorial somewhere.

Comment: This bunch of codes are used to get the values from SQL database. Whereby the user, clicks on the calendar and chooses the date and gets the chosen date printed out as title of the text file.

Yes, i'll go and do some reading to brush up on C#